# Vanishing Matrix as n approaches infinity

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the following: let A be a 2 x 2 matrix. Find a matrix A, such that A^n  = the zero matrix, as n approaches infinity.

I obviously know that the zero matrix works, but do any other examples come to mind?

Comment: Any matrix with "small" entries. Any nilpotent matrix.

Comment: Nilpotent matrices: if $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$, then $A^2=O$.

Comment: Any $\lambda I$ with $|\lambda| \lt 1\,$.

Comment: Any matrix with eigenvalues having magnitude less than 1. (In other words, any matrix similar to @dxiv's will also work.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nilpotent matrices is a straightforward example. I will try to generalize it for you. Now for the "non"-nilpotent matrices, they are diagonalizable (try to see for yourself). Thus $A=T\Lambda T^{-1}$ and $A^k=T\Lambda ^k T^{-1}$. Here $T$ is an invertible matrix and the $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues on the diagonal. Thus $A^k\rightarrow 0$, iff $\Lambda ^k\rightarrow 0$ which will happen only if the diagonal entries (eigenvalues) tend to zero for successive powers. Define the spectral radius $$\lambda_r=\max_{i}|\lambda_i|$$ which is the largest among the absolute values of the eigenvalues. Then, (convince yourself), the condition you want is equivalent to $\lambda_r<1$. Note that for a nilpotent matrix $\lambda_r=0$.